# How to make curved Debug.DrawLine in game view using LineRenderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I make this curved projectile line using line renderer through script?
I'm using Sebastian Lague's projectile script and he draws a line using Debug.DrawLine which is a gizmo and not visible in the build. I've used SetPosition but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

The Green line in the image is from the Debug.DrawLine and the red is the LineRenderer
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTtD4.jpg)

```
void DrawPath()
{
    LaunchData launchData = CalculateLaunchData();
    Vector3 previousDrawPoint = ball.position;

    int resolution = 30;
    for (int i = 1; i <= resolution; i++)
    {
        float simulationTime = i / (float)resolution * launchData.timeToTarget;
        Vector3 displacement = launchData.initialVelocity * simulationTime + Vector3.up * gravity * simulationTime * simulationTime / 2f;
        Vector3 drawPoint = ball.position + displacement;
        Debug.DrawLine(previousDrawPoint, drawPoint, Color.green);
        //I want to replace this with a line renderer
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, drawPoint);      
        previousDrawPoint = drawPoint;
    }
}
```

On play I'm getting an LineRenderer.SetPosition index out of bounds! error

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error due to the `LineRenderer` not having enough `vertices` than expected.

A `LineRenderer` have a [`positionCount`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-positionCount.html) variable, which you can set (and get). What you probably would want to do is this:

```
//...
int resolution = 30;
lineRenderer.positionCount = resolution;
for (int i = 1; i <= resolution; i++)
{
//...
```

This ensures that your Line Renderer have enough vertices before you start assigning positions to each vertice.

Since you are using a hard-coded value, you can safely set the `positionCount` on start/awake; Or even better, make it settable through the inspector.

Comment: Also note that [`SetPositions`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.SetPositions.html): `This method is preferred to SetPosition when setting all positions, as it is more efficient to set all positions using a single command than to set each position individually. `